# Uploading Image into SharePoint document library C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, sharepoint

I have a web service that currently passes base64 image format, However, How can I insert it into a sharepoint library? should i convert it to bytes array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, need to read image file stream and then use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect to save into SharePoint library:

```
            var fileName=@"C:\Test.jpg";
            using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://sp/"))
            {
                using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    var fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
                    var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
                    context.Load(list.RootFolder);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    var fileUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, fi.Name);

                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, fileUrl, fs, true);
                }
            }
```

Here is a similiar thread for your reference:

[How to Upload Images to SharePoint Online(Office 365) Picture-library using CSOM (Java Script)?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148633/how-to-upload-images-to-sharepoint-onlineoffice-365-picture-library-using-csom)